# docker private registry getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I am using self signed certificate with nginx  configuration while i am running below command i am getting error as below

root@ip-172-31-12-38:/etc/nginx/sites-available# docker push docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/busybox

The push refers to a repository [docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/busybox]
Put http://docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/v1/repositories/busybox/: dial tcp 13.126.242.122:5000: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: connection refused, means there is nothing listening on port 5000 on the destination server or that there is a firewall rejecting your request

Comment: what about the service? is it listening? Try running `netstat -ntpl` in the server

Comment: Plus, looks like your IP is an amazon one. If you are on AWS you need to adjust your security groups to allow traffic on port 5000 if you didn't already

Comment: What was the problem? About the new one, that looks like an authentication problem. Check registry's logs

Comment: thanks pal my issue is resolved now i am able to upload and download files with self signed certificate with  docker push and pull with  docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/busybox but how to display can i view this registry with URL such as https://docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/